# Editing mac scrollbars

Tags: html, css, macos, scrollbar, scrollbars

Is it possible to change or edit mac scrollbars via css? I can only find information on how to change chrome and firefox's scrollbars to make it look like os x. I've googled it and I can't find something.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width:9px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}
```

Comment: no, i meant change mac's own default scrollbar, not edit chrome and firefox's scrollbar to make it look like mac